# How to NSFileHandle a file got from another app

Tags: ios, file-io, nsfilehandle

I'm currently trying to implement the opening file from another app.
When I got to a third party app (like documents) and opening a file with my app, I can't seems to be able to open it with NSFileHandle.

After the AppDelegates method is called :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
```

I get an url like this :

```
file://localhost/private/var/mobile/Applications/E9F2998C-1ED2-4955-9681-30C518FBD1A5/Documents/Inbox/text%20source%20%C3%A0%20ID-7.docx
```

I have tried to remove manually `file://localhost/private` in order to look like a NSBunble path, but no luck...

Does anyone have a simple way to open with NSFileHandle an URL got from that delegate method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert the file `NSURL` value to an actual pathname that can be used by methods and functions that require a file path, call the `path` method.

```
if ([url isFileURL]) {
    NSString *filePath = [url path];
    // use filePath as needed
}
```

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "without titling"?